# Phalcon continue pagination in foreach

Tags: php, pagination, phalcon

I have a problem with pagination.
This is my code:

```
<?php foreach($paginator->items as $key => $item): if(empty($item->getTvguide($params)->toArray())) continue; ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="channel">
                <div class="channel-img pull-left">
                    <img src="<?=$item->icon?>" alt="publica">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix channel-name">
                    <h3><?=$item->title?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix channel-program">
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($item->getTvguide($params)->toArray() as $val): ?>   
                        <li><span><?=$val['time']?></span> <?=$val['prog']?></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When loop continue with if(empty...), I get empty results on pages. How can I get results on first page and remove empty results on pagination?

Code controller:

```
    $data = TvguideChannel::find();

    $paginator = new PaginatorModel(
        array(
            "data" => $data,
            "limit" => $limit,
            "page" => $curPage
        )
    );

    $params = [
        'columns' => 'distinct(time) as time, prog',
        'conditions' => $this->getType($this->request->get('type')) . ' AND ' . $this->getDay($this->request->get('day')) . ' AND ' . 'id_group = 13',
        'order' => 'time ASC'
    ];

    $items= $paginator->getPaginate();
```

Comment: Use criteria in your find()

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = TvguideChannel::find([
 'conditions' => $this->getType($this->request->get('type')) . ' AND ' . $this->getDay($this->request->get('day')) . ' AND ' . 'id_group = 13',
 'columns' => 'distinct(time) as time, prog',
 'limit' => $limit,
 'offset' => $curPage,
 'order' => 'time ASC'
]);
```

Something like that, don't forget to sanitize your condition.